# Where can you intentionally download computer virus online for testing purpose?

Tags: virus

I want to run Computer virus on virtual machine to see how they behave, is there any online repository or database which store computer virus. Both old and new?

Comment: I don't think it's completely off-topic. Perhaps if rephrased to something like: _"How can I test some existing computer viruses in a virtual machine (externally closed), in order to experience how they work? Where to find real ones?"_ it would be less attackable. However, it contains an implicit risk, __if not well controlled the viruses escape__... and it is not __[anymore so funny](https://superuser.com/q/1096317/257269)__.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to look at the [EICAR antivirus test file](https://www.eicar.org/?page_id=3950).

You can create this file by opening a text editor and pasting the following into it:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

The above text, in the words of the above site, is actually x86 machine language, and "... is a legitimate DOS program, and produces sensible results when run (it prints the message 'EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!')."

Comment: Whats the point though don't u want a virus not to print something?

Comment: It’s just for testing.

Answer (score 9):

There are various research sites that keep malware samples available for research. I found a list of sites that provide downloadable samples here: http://zeltser.com/combating-malicious-software/malware-sample-sources.html

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Also found a malware domain list: http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php