# Programs disapeared from the search bar

Tags: windows-11

After last update lots of my programs are not appearing anymore in the searchbar of windows.
Yet when I go to "Add or remove programs" I can still see them, I can still find them in their install folders and I can still launch them from their exec.

It just seems that the search functionnality forgot that they were installed. Also their icons disapeared from the taskbar.

How do I force a rebuild of the "database" of the programs installed on my computer ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Is it similar to this problem? https://superuser.com/questions/1762677/why-has-windows-defender-started-removing-shortcuts-today-13-01-2023

Comment: @DavidMarshall this is exacly that, we can close as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with Windows 11 Updates.

**(1) Try running DISM / SFC**

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(2) If DISM fails to correct the issue, run a Windows 11 Repair Install**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select download. Run the download, create a USB Key and  launch the Repair by running Setup on the USB key.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

If all the above fails, back up and reinstall Windows 11